# How to stick beak on head

Tags: modeling

Im making bird beak. The head is different and the beak is made with mirror modifier and subsurf modifier. I want to stick the beak to the head. I have used srinkwrap modifier make the vertex group of the corner edges. But did not work. Its having some gap between the beak and the head. Any suggestion or other modifier will work.

[image]

Gap between beak and head

When shrink modifier added i cant get the corner edge clean

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference image sharp edge need this way

[image]

Comment: Here is your answer: http://topologyguides.com/post/163096515095/decals and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s

Comment: remove doubles will help

Comment: @LukeD will i remove doubles and try your method its not working. Would you plz help how it work. Thanks

Comment: I would try to model this differently: extrude the beak from the head, after applying it subsurf. When you get your extruded beak shape, you can make it to appear to be sticking as a separate object would be... but the overall result would be way better, and much, much more easy to animate or deform...